# Computing multiple years that is a leap year in Java

Tags: java

What i'm trying to do is to create a leap year calculator that doesn't only calculate one year, but multiple years that a user can input. Right now, I only how to calculate one year.

Here's what the output is supposed to look like:

This program tests whether a given year is a leap year.

Type the starting year: 2008

Type the ending year: 2013

2008 is a leap year

2012 is a leap year

Thank you so much for your replies ! Helped me learn a lot more than what my lecturer actually teaches :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LeapYears
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in); 

System.out.println ("This program tests whether a given " + "year is a leap year.");

    System.out.print ("Type the starting year: ");
    int year = keyboard.nextInt ();

    System.out.print ("Type the ending year: ");
    int EndYear = keyboard.nextInt ();

if (((year%4 == 0) && (year%100 != 0)) || (year%400 == 0)) 

System.out.println (year + " is a leap year.");
    else
        System.out.println (year + " is not a leap year.");

} 
}
```

Comment: Looks like homework. Are you looking for loops? for, while?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap your leap year evaluation code in a method, and invoke it in a loop, example:

```
public boolean isLeapYear(int year){
   if (((year%4 == 0) && (year%100 != 0)) || (year%400 == 0)) 
       return true;
   else 
       return false;
}
```

and in your main method:

```
System.out.print("Type the starting year: ");
int startYear = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.print("Type the ending year: ");
int endYear = keyboard.nextInt();

for(int currentYear=startYear;currentYear++;currentYear<=endYear){
    if(isLeapYear(currentYear))
       System.out.println(currentYear + " is a leap year.");
    else
       System.out.println(currentYear + " is not a leap year.");
}
```

Other than that, it would be better to add some defensive code for the cases such as what user input is not integer, startYear is bigger than endYear.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    for(int y = year; y <= endYear; y++) {
        if (gc.isLeapYear(y)) {
            System.out.println(y + " is leap year");
        } else {
            System.out.println(y + " is not leap year");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use while loop for multiple years checking but Once you get first leap year, increase 4 years for next iteration(i.e. **year = year + 4;**). This way you can avoid unnecessary checking.

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("This program tests whether a given "
            + "year is a leap year.");

    System.out.print("Type the starting year: ");
    int year = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Type the ending year: ");
    int EndYear = keyboard.nextInt();

    while (year <= EndYear) {
        if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)) {

            System.out.println(year + " is a leap year.");
            year = year + 4;
        } else {
            //System.out.println(year + " is not a leap year.");
            year++;

        }
    }
```

Comment: `year = year++;` is not doing what you think.

Comment: There are more rules then just year% 4 ==0 check them all out here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm . basically if it's devisable by 4 but not 100 unless it's also decidable by 400 then it's a leap year.

Comment: I agree. thats why  year = year + 4; is fine. It only ensure year is divisible by 4 which is true for every leap year condition.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,it's a loop question.Try while loop like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LeapYear {
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in); 

        System.out.println ("This program tests whether a given " + "year is a leap year.");

        System.out.print ("Type the starting year: ");
        int year = keyboard.nextInt ();

        System.out.print ("Type the ending year: ");
        int EndYear = keyboard.nextInt ();
        int temp=year;
        while(temp<EndYear)
        {   if (((temp%4 == 0) && (temp%100 != 0)) || (temp%400 == 0)) {

                System.out.println (temp + " is a leap year.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println (temp + " is not a leap year.");
            }
            temp++;

        }


    } 
}
```